# In ExpressionEngine module development, where is a good place to add a PHP Class for instantiation?

Tags: php, class, module, expressionengine

I have a useful object written in PHP lets call it my_class.php

```
<?php
class my_class{
  var property;
  function __construct($conn){
     $query = "SELECT * FROM bla bla bla";
     $rs2 = mysql_query($query , $conn);
     //... do stuff with results etc.
  }
  function do_something(){
     //more code here
  }
}
?>
```

What I would like to do with this class is to be able to use it inside of the admin section of the EE site, in the following way:

```
$this_obj = new my_class($conn);
```

The concerns that arise from this are the following:
1) $conn would be a connection to MySql when you're sort of outside EE, and it would be better to place this somewhere where it is possible to use the EE database calls.

2) where would you put a class, so that EE can instiantate it many times?

To make this object useful, it will need to be instantiated dozens of times, and I'll want to be using an array of these objects rather than just one instance.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look through the [CodeIgniter docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide). ExpressionEngine is based on CI, so if you're looking for best practices look at the CI docs.

You can store your class files wherever you want - but most people store the in libraries/ or lib/ within the addon folder they are developing. That way you can call $this->EE->load->library('whatever');

Take a look at models for making database calls - also take a look at the [CI DB / ActiveRecord](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html) Class and the [DB forge](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html) class.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks!  That's kind of where I'm headed with this, I'm looking into maybe looping a $this->load->library('my_class', '', 'reference_name'); or seeing if calling it once will allow me to construct many objects from this class.

Comment: Once you have the library you can make as many objects - no need to put it inside the loop.

Comment: Yep.  The instantiating is working now.  Once I have the MySql part figured out and working, I'll post a solid example.

Comment: Please post the example - would love to see it

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to instantiate an object that can handle its own MySQL within an EE Module's control panel.

The control panel is in the .mcp file for your module, and as Philip stated, using this as a library is the way to go.

The class file located in expressionengine/third_party/your_module/libraries/my_class.php

```
<?php
class my_class{
  var property;
  function __construct(){
     $this->EE = & get_instance();
  }
  function init($some_id){
     $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE whatever='$some_id' ";
     $results = $this->EE->db->query($query);
     if ($results->num_rows() > 0) {
         foreach ($results->result_array() as $row) {
           //do your thing here
         }
     }
  }
  function do_something(){
     //more code here
     return $results;
  }
}
```

Now that this code is in the right place, the library folder, you can access it from your mcp file, from within whatever method will be serving up your view.

```
//somewhere in the method you're using in your module
$this->EE->load->library('my_class.php', '', 'reference_name');
//passing something here to the constructor will throw warnings.
$obj = new $this->EE->reference_name();
$obj->init($some_id);
$tmp = $obj->do_something();
```

$obj above is an instance of the my_class class, and $tmp will be whatever the do_something method yields.  There is no need to pass the object a MySQL connection, ExpressionEngine does that for you if you have that first line in the constructor above.